# Is there any way to set different 'spanCount' for each row based on item text-length for RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android

Actually I'm trying to design below page for my current app.

[image: Expected Screen]

If you observe the above screen-shot carefully, you'll see the `Span-Count` in each row is different (Sometimes it 2/3/1) and it seems like these items are adjusted based on the respective `item text-length` OR `Item-Width`. So, considering these points I'm trying to design this page. Currently I'm using `RecyclerView` with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`

Below is my code:

```
rvCategory = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvCategory);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
rvCategory.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(9, 15));
rvCategory.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Using above code, my screen is looking as below--

[image]

You can clearly notice the difference between the First Screen-Shot (Expected) and the Second Screen-Shot (Now Looking), the second screen shot showing fixed Span-Count (i.e. 3.  Of-course it is set in the code) also the text on the item is not completely  visible.

Comment: You can use [Chip](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/) and [ChipGroup](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use  `FlowLayoutManager`

```
implementation 'com.xiaofeng.android:flowlayoutmanager:1.2.3.2'
```

and for `RecyclerView`

```
FlowLayoutManager flowLayoutManager = new FlowLayoutManager();
flowLayoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(flowLayoutManager);
```